# Why do nucleons pair up?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

I'm learning about the [semi-empirical mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula) currently, and in the explanation for the pairing term, the course notes say that it's energetically favorable for nucleons to pair up.
Could someone explain this to me intuitively?

Comment: Do you understand the analogous situation for electrons pairing up in the electron shell structure of the atom?

Comment: Related but not quite a duplicate: [Pairing term in semi-empirical mass formula and nature of spin-dependence of nuclear forces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/784171/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nucleons pair up in atomic nuclei because of the Pauli exclusion principle, which states that no two fermions can occupy the same quantum state.

Nucleons tend to pair up with opposite spins, which allows them to occupy the same orbital state but maintain unique quantum states. This pairing is energetically favorable because it allows nucleons to be closer together, thus experiencing a stronger attractive force (the strong nuclear force), and occupying lower energy states, leading to more stable nuclear configurations.

The semi-empirical mass formula includes a pairing term to account for this effect, indicating that nuclei with even numbers of protons and neutrons are more stable due to complete nucleon pairing, while those with odd numbers are less stable due to the presence of unpaired nucleons. This pairing phenomenon contributes to the overall stability and binding energy of atomic nuclei.